# R: Creating Yearly / Within Country Averages

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a mean variable which calculates the mean country-level value for observations within a country across different years.

My data looks like this:

```
party_id year country position
    101 1984      be     2.75
    101 1988      be     2.75
    101 1992      be     3.33
    101 1996      be     3.67
    102 1984      be     5.80
    102 1988      be     5.80
```

For example I would like a mean variable which would have the mean position of all parties in Belgium for 1984, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Using `aggregate` you can get the average by country and year

```
aggregate(position ~ country + year, data = df,  mean)

  country year position
1      be 1984    4.275
2      be 1988    4.275
3      be 1992    3.330
4      be 1996    3.670
```

Another, perhaps more readable, way is to use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  summarise(mean(position))
```

**Edit** - OP request to add variable to data you can use `mutate`

```
df %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  mutate(mean(position))
```

base solution suggested by @bouncyball

```
merge(x = df,y = aggregate(position~year+country, data = df, FUN = mean), 
      by = c('year','country'))
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I then create a new variable with the means, so that the number of rows is large enough, and the observations match up?

Comment: In base you could: `merge(x = df,y = aggregate(pos~year+country, data = df, FUN = mean),
                  by.x = c('year','country'), by.y = c('year','country'))`

Comment: @bouncyball thanks, can actually simplify further to `by = c('year', 'country')` as names are the same.